# What is the correct way to translate .NET Rijndael Managed AES decrypt function to Java

Tags: java, vb.net, aes, rijndael

Need help to convert the following example code from .NET VB code to java to include in a jsp page. I have looked at a number of questions that all seem to have partial answers.

```
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal TokenKey As String, ByVal DataString As String) As String
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = Nothing
        Dim cs As CryptoStream = Nothing
        Try
            Using AES As New RijndaelManaged()
                AES.KeySize = 128
                AES.BlockSize = 128
                Dim EncryptedData As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(DataString)
                Dim SecretKey As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(TokenKey, New Byte() {<Your salt>})
                Using Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(16), SecretKey.GetBytes(16))
                    ms = New MemoryStream(EncryptedData)
                    Using ms
                        cs = New CryptoStream(ms, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                        Using cs
                            Dim PlainText As Byte() = New Byte(EncryptedData.Length - 1) {}
                            Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(PlainText, 0, cs.Read(PlainText, 0, PlainText.Length))
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "Error - " & ex.Message
        Finally
            If ms IsNot Nothing Then
                ms.Close()
            End If
            If cs IsNot Nothing Then
                cs.Close()
            End If
        End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions on stackoverflow that I had to lookup and each provided parts of the puzzle. Here is a working java solution for the above example. The key to the solution is the following:

Explanation as requested:

The .NET Rijendael implementation uses AES in CBC mode along with PKCS#7 padding for the underlying algorithm

RFC2898 Key derivation is the same as using java PBKFD2 for newer implementations

On windows the encoding for the cipher requires UTF-16LE

Final result for decryption requires a 'new String' rather than byte[] toString

Note: the solution uses AES with 128 bits but can be changed to 256 with the proper allocation of the subsequent key and modifying array copies accordingly, however, the blocksize of 128 cannot be changed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


/**
  * Hello world!
  *
  */
public class App 
{
private final String extCharEnc = "UTF-8";
private final String intCharEnc = "UTF-16LE";
private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";
private final byte[] salt = {<Your salt>};

public  byte[] decryptInternal(byte[] cipherText, String sharedKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1"); 
    //Please note that the last parameter in the following function is key size (128) + blocksize 128 = 256
    //If you do use an AES keysize of 256 then the last parameter will be 384 etc.
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(sharedKey.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
    Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    byte[] key = new byte[16];
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 16);
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 16, iv, 0, 16);

    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivSpec);
    return(cipher.doFinal(cipherText));

}

public byte[] encryptInternal(String plaintext, String sharedKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");   
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(sharedKey.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
    Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    byte[] key = new byte[16];
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 16);
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 16, iv, 0, 16);

    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivSpec);
    return(cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes(intCharEnc)));

}

/// <summary>
/// Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plainText">Plain text to encrypt</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret key</param>
/// <returns>Base64 encoded string</returns>
public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException{
    return URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptInternal(plainText, key)), extCharEnc);
}

/// <summary>
/// Decrypts a base64 encoded string using the given key (AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="encryptedText">Base64 Encoded String</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret Key</param>
/// <returns>Decrypted String</returns>
public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String sharedKey) throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException{
   String cipheredBytes = URLDecoder.decode(encryptedText, extCharEnc);       
   return new String(decryptInternal(Base64.decodeBase64(cipheredBytes), sharedKey), intCharEnc);
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{ 
    App myApp = new App();
    String SharedKey = <Your Shared Key>;
    String InputStr =  <Test string to encrypt and decrypt>;

    String EncryptedStr = null;
    String DecryptedStr = null;

    try {
        EncryptedStr = myApp.encrypt(InputStr, SharedKey);
        DecryptedStr = myApp.decrypt(EncryptedStr, SharedKey);
        System.out.println( "This is the Encrypted String: " + EncryptedStr + " \nThis is the Decrypted String: " + DecryptedStr);
    } catch (KeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: 1. The answer needs a description, not just code. 2. Rijndael with a KeySize of 128-bits and a blockSize of 128-bits is the same as AES, there is no conversion. The code is example is really about implementation in both java and vb.net.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have updated the answer. This exercise started out with someone providing me the VB.Net code and I had to discover the java equivalent solution and there wasnt one comprehensive solution